# How to create Dynamic Model In laravel?

Tags: excel, laravel, model

Suppose I have two excel sheet named as flower and fruit. When I am importing the flower excel sheet, I can use the predefine Flower Model, when importing the fruit excel sheet, I can use the predefine Fruit Model. Now if I want to import a random excel sheet ( where the number of columns and column title is unknown), how can I create a random model and its attributes for importing the excel sheet.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the model. Save it to database? In that case you'll get problem with column names. You could try to create a very basic and genetic model, with a JSON field where you store the column and value information.

Comment: @MaartenVeerman yes, I need to store data in the database. If you have enough free time, can you give me a demo example of how to create a generic model?  Thank you so much for your valuable feedback.